# removing BBcode from textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, bbcode, phpbb3

I'm creating a small javscript for phpBB3 forum, that counts how much character you typed in. 
But i need to remove the special characters(which i managed to do so.) and one BBcode: quote

my problem lies with the quote...and the fact that I don't know much about regex.

this is what I managed to do so far but I'm stranded:

http://jsfiddle.net/emjkc/

```
var text = '';
var char = 0;


  text = $('textarea').val();
  text = text.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}!?(\r\n|\n|\r)]/gm, '');
  char = text.length;
  $('div').text(char);
$('textarea').bind('input propertychange', function () {

    text = $(this).val();
    text = text.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}!?\-\–_;(\r\n|\n|\r)]/gm, '');

    char = text.length;
    $('div').text(char);
});
```

Comment: can [quote] elements be nested?

Comment: Yes. it can be nexted up to three times.

Comment: you want just to strip the bbcode tag or also the contents between [quote] and [/quote]?

Comment: the content as well. I'm trying to count how much the user typed in himself, not how much he can quote.

Comment: You better use a parser for that, not a regex.

Comment: this JS is only for indicating how much the user is typing in. For PH version tere is already a Mod implemented for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better write a parser for that, however if you want to try with regexes, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4XxWk/6/) should do the trick:

```
text = $('textarea').val();
while (text.match(/\[quote.*\[\/quote\]/i) != null) {
   //remove the least inside the innermost found quote tags 
   text = text.replace(/^(.*)\[quote.*?\[\/quote\](.*)$/gmi, '\$1\$2');
}
// now strip anything non-character
text = text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi, '');
```

Comment: that didnt strip whats inside the Quote. And what do you meany by writting a parser? a function for this?

Comment: okay never mind. the jsfiddle one didnt but after I switched the replace's order it started working. the order is correct in the answer thank you! - JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TS26r/

Comment: mmh actually it is still malfunctioning in case of unbalanced tags

Comment: ok I changed a bit the match regex and updated the fiddle and now it's better

Comment: +1, you were right, a small parser sounds better than a single regex hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work, but I think you can replace all bbcodes with a regex like this:

```
var withoutBBCodes = message.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g,"");
```

It just replaces everything like `[any char != ']' goes here]`

EDIT: sorry, didn't see that you only want to replace [quote] and not all bbcodes:

```
var withoutBBQuote = message.replace(/\[[\/]*quote[^\]]*\]/g,"");
```

EDIT: ok, you also want quoted content removed:

```
while (message.indexOf("[quote") != -1) {
    message = message.replace(/\[quote[^\]]*\]((?!\[[[\/]*quote).)*\[\/quote\]/g,"");
}
```

I know you already got a solution thanks to @guido but didn't want to leave this answer wrong.

Comment: yes it doesnt counts the characters between two quotes, i see. i jumped the gun. thanks for notyfing me notheless.

Comment: replaced the last regex with a while loop with a regex that removes nested quotes until no more quotes are found. The while will run up to 3 times if you have up to 3 levels of nested quotes.