# Javascript Making BBcode regex ungreedy

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode, phpbb3

thanks to another question: [removing BBcode from textarea with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956837/removing-bbcode-from-textarea-with-javascript)
I managed to create this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hVgAh/1/

```
 text = $('textarea').val();
while (text.match(/\[quote.*\[\/quote\]/i) != null) {
   //remove the least inside the innermost found quote tags 
   text = text.replace(/^(.*)\[quote.*?\[\/quote\](.*)$/gmi, '\$1\$2');
}
text = text.replace(/\[\/?[^\[\]]+\]/gmi,'');
// now strip anything non-character
//text = text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi, '');
  char = text.length;
  $('div').text(text);
```

this code does remove the quote bbcode ( and other BBcode as well), but it only removes the content of the  deepest quote, or last qoute that it will ever see. I think the reason for this is that the regex is greedy. But i tried to make it not greedy by adding `?` but i didnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/hVgAh/2/

i need to remove all the quotes with its content. How can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695658/1400768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to strip the newlines: to match any character *including* newlines use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

The multiline modifier `m`, which makes the anchor tags `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line instead of the whole string, is unnecessary also.

Here is a solution that also avoids the repeated `match` calls:

```
var t;
while ( t != text ) {
    t = text;
    //text = text.replace( /\[quote(?:(?!\[quote)[\s\S])+?\[\/quote\]/g, '' );
    text = text.replace( /^([\s\S]*)\[quote[\s\S]+?\[\/quote\]/g, '$1');
}
```

The commented-out line is an alternative version which should work equally well.

Instead of a greedy match it uses a negative look-ahead to ensure that only the deepest quote tags are matched. It is enclosed in parentheses with the `[\s\S]` so that it looks ahead before every character between the quote tags is matched, and prevents a match if `[quote` appears.

It is hard to say which would be more efficient.

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wj95J/).

Comment: thanks! this works great! I have changed my code since then, and this even revealed a bug in it, that wasn't good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the greedyness, but that replace didnt go beyond newline even with the `m` modifier. i replaced newlines with nothing, so the whole textarea became one line, and suddenly it worked like a charm.

```
text = $('textarea').val();
text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gmi, '');
while (text.match(/\[quote.*\[\/quote\]/i) != null) {
    //remove the least inside the innermost found quote tags 
    text = text.replace(/^(.*)\[quote.*?\[\/quote\](.*)$/gmi, '\$1\$2');
}
text = text.replace(/\[\/?[^\[\]]+\]/gmi, '');
text = text.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gmi, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NaGeL182/dJvuZ/